# Как сделать размер ScrollView равным размеру контента?

Tags: ios

Как сделать размер ScrollView равным размеру контента?

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.size = scrollView.contentSize;
scrollView.frame = frame;
```